# Paypal Integration

Tags: payment-gateway, payment, paypal, payment-processing

I am quite new to PayPal integration into website. What are the basics of paypal integration? What type of sandbox account do i need to create?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For sandbox account, you can go to www.developer.paypal.com and start an account. The basics of paypal integration? Thats too generic to answer but i suggest you go to www.x.com to read up on forum threads.

Comment: which paypal payment method should me use? 
Express Checkout or Website Payments Standard API ?

@pivotal developer

Answer (score 6):

What he said. 
You can sign up for a developer account at https://developer.paypal.com/ - this allows you to set up multiple buyer/seller accounts.
Keep in mind that Sandbox is fully separated from the live environment; so any emails will be directed to the 'Test emails' section on https://developer.paypal.com/ rather than being sent out externally.
Should you need to get specific access to an API call (i.e., Reference Transactions), just log a thread at x.com or paypal.com/mts

Comment: The x.com did not work for me, but, the paypal.com/mts worked.

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a test PayPal account. First of all you can sign up for a developer account on the paypal website https://developer.paypal.com and two types of account can be created.

1. Buyer (Personal)
2. Seller (Business)

You also login with sandbox account to check the transactions at https://sandbox.paypal.com.

You can also refer to this link:
http://www.phpgang.com/how-to-integrate-payment-system-with-paypal_249.html